# Twig satement doesnt prevent trans_default_domain to be set

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this small snippet of code.

```
{% if app.user.type is defined and app.user.type == 1 %}
{% trans_default_domain 'otherdomain' %}
{% endif %}
```

For some reason the default_domain is always set!
Other code I put inside this statement only runs when the conditions are met.

Does anyone know why this happens? And or know a solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: Aparently I can reset to the actual default domain ('messages') if I expand my logic with an else statement.

Comment: sorry but I have to ask: did you clear the cache?

Comment: can you try `{% if app.user.type is defined and app.user.type == 1 %}
   {% set domainName = 'otherdomain' %}
{% endif %}
{% trans_default_domain domainName|default('default') %}`

Comment: Yes I cleared the cache! :)

Comment: Also, setting a variable and using that in the statement works; But this is just a workaround. I want to know why and how the statement gets fired even if it's false. And why it looks like it doesn't execute ( can't dump any vars in the statement, but it sets that trans variable every time ).